# Keep track of location updates after the app gets killed

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, geolocation, gps

In my app, I ask the user to accept the location tracking for `always`. I can successfully track his location while he's on the app with `locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()` and

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        print("Latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude), Longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
    }
```

But the thing is that even though the user accepted the location tracking all of the time, I stop getting the location updates when the app gets killed. How can I do to keep getting the updates 24/7 ? Can I add something to AppDelegate ? Thank you

Comment: No, if an app is in background then OS automically put your app on suspended state and not able to take cordinates, other wise you need to do background thread for location manager